# Elastic Search Difficult Query with Grouping

Tags: search, elasticsearch, filter, grouping, fuzzy-search

I am new to Elastic Search (1.7).
I have the ES index of a client’s versions.

Each client has a unique Id (client_id).

There are many versions of a client can be in the index.

Each version of a client has a unique id (version_id) for the client.

Index Data Example:

```
{
  “client_id”: "1",
  "version_id": "1",
  “versionCreationDate”: "2015-11-06T10:02:22.597Z",
  “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
}
…,
{
  “client_id”: "1",
  "version_id": "n",
  “versionCreationDate”: …
  “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
},
{
  “client_id”: "2",
  "version_id": "1",
  “versionCreationDate”: …
  “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
},
…
{
  “client_id”: "2",
  "version_id": "n",
  “versionCreationDate”: …
  “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
},
…
{
  “client_id”: "N",
  "version_id": "1",
  “versionCreationDate”: …
  “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
},
…
{
  “client_id”: "N",
  "version_id": "n",
  “versionCreationDate”: …
    “clientName”: “FirstName LastName”
}
```

I need to find client’s versions by input parameters for query:

<*clientName*>, <*VersionCreationDateMax*>.

Client's versions should match <*clientName*> (with fuzziness=auto). And any version must have maximum value of versionCreationDate for this client, but <=  <*VersionCreationDateMax*>. So the only one version of each client should be in search results (newest, but not more than <*VersionCreationDateMax*>)

Please help me in finding the filter/query to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following query:

- one `range` filter to specify the max `versionCreationDate`
- then one `terms` aggregation on the `client_id` field
- finally, for each client bucket, one `top_hits` sub-aggregation sorted in `desc` order on the `versionCreationDate` field and only returning one document (i.e. `size: 1`)

Here is the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "versionCreationDate": {
            "lt": "2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "clients": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "client_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "versionCreationDate": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Comment: Val, this works, but _score is just only in "hits" section of results. And it's ==null in "aggregations" section. Why? How make ES to return_score in aggregations section?

Comment: By default, the score in a top hits aggregation defaults to the score of the main query. Since your query only contains filters, there's no scoring involved.

Comment: thank you for your help! Look at my query and result: quite usual query with aggregation and without filters. There is a _score in the hits section and null in aggregations section. [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E33E98A88C1751AF!3356&authkey=!AJUJAhAxrBD4OhM&ithint=folder%2cpng)

Comment: I don't see any query in your question, only some sample documents.

Comment: Val, query is in the txt / png files (onedrive link above). It's too big to write it in a comment. This is part of query:
{
 "size": 1,
//"from": 20,
     "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                 { "match": {"_all": {"query": "test","operator": "and","fuzziness": "2"}}}
             ],
             "should": [
                 { "multi_match" : {
                         "query":      "test"
                         ,"type":       "best_fields"
                         ,"fields":     ["ObjectData.PRTNAME","ObjectData.EXTERNALID","ObjectData.contactList.VAL..

Comment: Please update your question with the query in text form, it's easier to search than on a screenshot and it's ok to have it in your question even if it's big.

Comment: Val, I created another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175750/elastic-search-score-is-null-in-aggregations-why